# How to write a formula that fits these criteria in Excel

Tags: excel

I have this sample dataset. Does anyone knows the formula for column E should be in Excel?

It needs to group by the Name in column B and if Paid By in column D contains "Credit Card" then update Payment Type in column E for each row with "Credit Card".

For example, if the same name, paid by "Credit Card" for one instance, then the Payment Type will be "Credit Card" for the same name.

[image]

Comment: This makes no sense. Please give more detail to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: From your dataset we can summaries that, if anyone pay by cash then payment type will be `Other` and all other will be `Credit Card`?

Comment: For example, if the same name, paid by "Credit Card" for one instance, then the Payment Type will be "Credit Card" for the same name.

Comment: @karweng what should be in column E if the 10th item is "John | Pencil | Credit Card" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user is probably looking for a formula like, if the customer ever paid with a Credit Card state "Credit Card" (as he has one) or "Other" if he **never** used a Credit Card.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($B$3:$B$8;"="&B3;$D$3:$D$8;"=Credit Card");"Credit Card";"Other")
```

As Screen Shot:
[image]

Simply use COUNTIFS, which allows mutliple criteria. Hence count all rows with the same Name and count if Credit Card was ever used. If >0 state "Credit Card".

Comment: Thanks HaPi, that formula worked a treat.